# MongoDB/Mongoose update array within array with $addToSet

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose-schema

Good day all,

i'm trying to save image galleries where each image can have up to 5 tags associated with them. So in the Document the Gallery field is an array that has multiple values of which the Tag attribute which itself is an array of Tags.

I'm having issue saving an image where the user adds 2 or more tags for that picture. below this is what i have in my mongoose user schema

```
    gallery : [{
        origin : {type: String, trim: true, default: null},
        uploadOn: {type: Date, Default: null},
        title: { type: String, trim: true, default: null},
        caption: { type: String, trim: true, default: null },
        tag: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Imagetag', unique: true, sparse: true }],
        imageLink: { type: String, trim: true }
    }]
```

and this is my update script

```
var query = {username:'testUser'};
var options = { runValidators: true };
var toUpdate = {
      $addToSet : {
        gallery : {
         origin : req.body.orgin,
         uploadOn: new Date(),
         title: req.body.title,
         caption: req.body.caption,

         tag: '59a5fea0382f1305841f0d86' // working
         $addToSet: { tag: { $each: ['59a5fea0382f1305841f0d86', '59a5fea0382f1305841f0d88'] } } , // not working
         $push: { tag: { $each: ['59a5fea0382f1305841f0d86', '59a5fea0382f1305841f0d88'] } } , // not working

         imageLink: req.body.path
       }
     }
};

// proceed to update
var user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(query, toUpdate, options);
```

i have listed the different combination that i have tried without success. i do not want to have to make multiple calls to update the tags one by one for that same image.

Comment: It does not work like that. "Inside" an existing `$addToSet` operation where adding a new item to "gallery", you would simply supply the array with no other operator i.e `tag: ['59a5fea0382f1305841f0d86', '59a5fea0382f1305841f0d88']`. So you don't actually nest the operators themselves, and it's not valid because operators are "top-level" only in the update document, for the plain reason that they describe what to do.

Comment: If you wanted to add to that "separately" in a different request, then you would update to match an existing array member and use the positional `$` operator to denote which matched element to update `User.findOneAndUpdate({username:'testUser', 'gallery.tile': 'unique title' }, { $addToSet: { 'gallery.$.tag': { $each:
 ['59a8900de346eacb1074cc5a','59a8905ce346eacb1074cc5b'] } },{ new: true })`. But that's a separate request. For doing it all at once, it's just one chunk of data.

Comment: thanks used the tag: ['59a5fea0382f1305841f0d86', '59a5fea0382f1305841f0d88'] and it worked as expected